# Unable to start ignite client in spring

Tags: spring-boot, ignite

I have a Spring cloud project which uses cache mechanism. We are using ignite cache in application by adding the dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
      <artifactId>ignite-rest-http</artifactId>
      <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

In properties tag we mentioned the ignite version as 2.7.0(Client). The ignite standalone server also having the same version which is running in the same machine.I am getting the below given error while trying to start the application.

```
    [19:45:37,471][SEVERE][restartedMain][IgniteKernal] Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=o.a.i.i.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
    class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@334f6d54], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:300)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:939)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1682)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1066)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2038)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1730)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1158)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:656)
        at org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpring.start(IgniteSpring.java:66)
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.spring.SpringCacheManager.onApplicationEvent(SpringCacheManager.java:332)
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.spring.SpringCacheManager.onApplicationEvent(SpringCacheManager.java:146)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:897)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
        at com.ibs.ps.PsAuthServiceApplication.main(PsAuthServiceApplication.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
    Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Local node and remote node have different version numbers (node will not join, Ignite does not support rolling updates, so versions must be exactly the same) [locBuildVer=2.8.0, rmtBuildVer=2.7.0, locNodeAddrs=[test.test.com/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1, /192.168.00.00], rmtNodeAddrs=[127.0.0.1], locNodeId=9aa05a68-b0f4-4fa9-b288-cc7c32caf691, rmtNodeId=14ea4223-b6e7-4084-b5a8-89481d99de53]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.checkFailedError(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1946)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$MessageWorker.body(ClientImpl.java:1888)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ClientImpl$1.body(ClientImpl.java:304)
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)
```

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to the exception:

Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Local node and remote node have different version numbers (node will not join, Ignite does not support rolling updates, so versions must be exactly the same) [locBuildVer=2.8.0, rmtBuildVer=2.7.0, locNodeAddrs=[test.test.com/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1, /192.168.00.00], rmtNodeAddrs=[127.0.0.1], locNodeId=9aa05a68-b0f4-4fa9-b288-cc7c32caf691, rmtNodeId=14ea4223-b6e7-4084-b5a8-89481d99de53]

It's not possible to have a mixed cluster in Apache Ignite. 
You should choose either 2.8.0 or 2.7.0.

The GridGain edition does allow you to have a cluster with a multiple versions though.